# How can I expand or detokenize a macro before using it in a hyperlink?

Tags: hyperref, detokenize, expandafter

So I have some information stored in a macro that is used already elsewhere and can contain formatting macros like `\small` or similar and I want to expand or detokenize those commands before also using the content for the subject of a hyperlink. This is what I expected to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\subject{\small This is my subject}

\begin{document}
    \href{mailto:jane.doe@domain.com?subject=\expandafter\detokenize{\subject}}{Send an email}
\end{document}
```

However in this case `\subject` is never expanded, as you can see from the PDF viewer:

[image]

So what is the appropriate way of expanding `\subject`and thereby get rid of the `\small`?

Comment: You need `\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\subject}`, this won't get rid of `\small` but at least will be able to expand `\subject`.

Comment: If you expand `\subject` you *will* get `\small`.

Comment: @Jinwen `\detokenize\expandafter{\subject}` would suffice, although of course it doesn't take care of `\small`.

Comment: @egreg It seems I will never master expansion in LaTeX. ;-) How can I then get rid of any formatting command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much like Jinwin's answer but using the expandable text expander in `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \PurifyText \text_purify:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\subject{\small This is my subject}

\begin{document}

\href{mailto:jane.doe@domain.com?subject=\detokenize\expandafter{\expanded{\PurifyText{\subject}}}}{Send an email}

\end{document}
```

Here `\text_purify:n` *does* remove formatting.

Comment: One could wrap the detokenization, etc., into a command of course

Answer (score 2):

If your formatting macros doesn't contain a space in it after detokenize, then you can use `\StrBehind` from package `xstring` to extract the text after the first space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\subject{\small This is my subject}

\begin{document}

\StrBehind{\detokenize\expandafter{\subject}}{ }[\temp]

\href{mailto:jane.doe@domain.com?subject=\temp}{Send an email}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But this only works if the formatting is the first macro. It could also be `\small Hello my \textbf{friend}` and I would just like to get the characters without any formatting.

Comment: @TobiBS Then the most simple solution would be to keep two version of your text, formatted version and plain text version. Of course one can also use regex to remove the formatting macro but I don't think that's worth the effort.

Comment: @TobiBS Oh, wait, I just noticed that there is a `\text_purify:n` in LaTeX3, I shall improve my answer soon.

Comment: @TobiBS Joseph Wright has achieved this, check his wonderful solution ;)